# Suppressing schannel output on Windows

Tags: windows, ssl, curl

I've been using cURL for a while now, though not upgrading the executable very often. I've noticed with v7.60 that when using `-v` to get the headers as well, I get a smattering of `* schannel:` messages in the prompt, so that it goes like this:

```
$ curl -vs "https://example.com"
* Rebuilt URL to: https://example.com/
*   Trying 93.184.216.34...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to example.com (93.184.216.34) port 443 (#0)
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with example.com port 443 (step 1/3)
* schannel: checking server certificate revocation
* schannel: sending initial handshake data: sending 176 bytes...
* schannel: sent initial handshake data: sent 176 bytes
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with example.com port 443 (step 2/3)
* schannel: failed to receive handshake, need more data
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with example.com port 443 (step 2/3)
* schannel: encrypted data got 4096
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 4096 length 4096
* schannel: encrypted data length: 14
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 14 length 4096
* schannel: received incomplete message, need more data
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with example.com port 443 (step 2/3)
* schannel: encrypted data got 817
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 831 length 4096
* schannel: sending next handshake data: sending 126 bytes...
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with example.com port 443 (step 2/3)
* schannel: encrypted data got 242
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 242 length 4096
* schannel: SSL/TLS handshake complete
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with example.com port 443 (step 3/3)
* schannel: stored credential handle in session cache
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: example.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.60.0
> Accept: */*
>
* schannel: client wants to read 102400 bytes
* schannel: encdata_buffer resized 103424
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 0 length 103424
* schannel: encrypted data got 1666
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 1666 length 103424
* schannel: decrypted data length: 338
* schannel: decrypted data added: 338
* schannel: decrypted data cached: offset 338 length 102400
* schannel: encrypted data length: 1299
* schannel: encrypted data cached: offset 1299 length 103424
* schannel: decrypted data length: 1270
* schannel: decrypted data added: 1270
* schannel: decrypted data cached: offset 1608 length 102400
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 0 length 103424
* schannel: decrypted data buffer: offset 1608 length 102400
* schannel: schannel_recv cleanup
* schannel: decrypted data returned 1608
* schannel: decrypted data buffer: offset 0 length 102400
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Cache-Control: max-age=604800
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Date: Tue, 05 Feb 2019 08:08:57 GMT
< Etag: "1541025663"
< Expires: Tue, 12 Feb 2019 08:08:57 GMT
< Last-Modified: Fri, 09 Aug 2013 23:54:35 GMT
< Server: ECS (dca/24C1)
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< X-Cache: HIT
< Content-Length: 1270
<
[HTML here]
```

Is there any way to suppress these messages so that `-v` still yields me the headers, and I can use `> NUL` to discard the response body, all without the SChannel noise?
To head off the obvious suggestion, `-I` won't work for me: I *need* to be able to send `GET` and other requests this way because my work involves investigating third-party servers that can (and have been known to) respond to `HEAD` differently.

Comment: Just pass in `-i` (include headers) instead of `-v` (be verbose). I beleieve `- D` is what you need if you care about the headers ONLY.

Comment: `-D` doesn't seem to be a recognized option in v7.60... I'm probably misunderstanding where to add it, but I can't find this in the manpage either.
Oh, and can you add the `-i` as an answer? _That_ seems to be what I'm looking for, and I want to accept it properly.